# Find probabilities of getting the right area code of a subscriber-number-only phone contact

Tags: probability, statistics

Situation: I have 100 contacts on my phonebook.  We can tell what area by looking at a number.  For example **+61 8 1234 5678**, this is an Australian phone number where

- +61  country code
- 8  area code (WA for Western Australia)
- 1234 5678 subscriber number

Problem:
If I have a contact that contains **1234 5678** only, assuming that all my contacts are in Australia and more than half of the contacts are from WA, what are the chances that this number falls on WA?

Question: What branch in mathematics do I need to read? I'm guessing that this falls on probability and statistics? If my guess is right, what topic in probability and statistics do I need to focus?

I'm looking for the right branch/topic in math to read on.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [conditional probabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).